# How to write an AAR in my Android Application?

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I'm trying to write a simple AAR into my Android application. My code follows:

```
        NdefMessage ndefMessage = createNdefMessage("1");
        writeNdefMessage(tag,ndefMessage);
        NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.example.myapp");
```

When I build the application, my NdefMessage of "1" shows up without any problem...but my AAR isn't working? I'm doing something stupid and I need another set of eyes...I appreciate any help, thanks!!!

Comment: If you dont like the native API, try https://github.com/skjolber/ndef-tools-for-android

Answer (score 1):

You create a NdefMessage containing only one record. 
Assuming that you want to write the "1" as a text string, you might code it like:

```
NdefRecord[] ndefRecords;
ndefRecords[0] = NdefRecord.createTextRecord ("en", "1");
ndefRecords[1] = NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.example.myapp");
NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(ndefRecords);
writeNdefMessage(tag, ndefMessage);
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the help, Corvairjo. I'm also wondering if there was a way to assign an "ID" to the tag using the Ndef record? For example, can I use the ndefRecord as an ID that is physically written to the tag? My thought would be that the application would "read" that ID and then execute a specific portion of code depending on the Ndef value that was discovered upon scan. Does that make sense and is that even possible? I don't have much experience with NFC, sorry if this  isn't clear!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "ID". It that is a number, text of combination of both, which you assign to the tag, then you can create another record and put that ID there. When you read the tag later, you can process the data of that record and act accordingly.

Comment: Hi corvairjo, I've actually been able to write an "ID" to an NFC tag via the createExternal method. The problem I'm having now is getting my other application to actually "read" the payload that has been written to the tag.

How would I go about actually "reading" the payload that has been written to an NFC tag? Is there a place here that I could post add'l code?

Comment: See my answer to your other post.